# I try to move box from left to right and back again, but it crashes after a few cycles

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript and one of my exercises was to move box from left to right. It works fine first few cycles, but then it gets messy and I have no idea what causes that.

```
    function preparePage(){
        var box = document.getElementById("box");
        var leftPosition = 0;
        box.style.position = "absolute";

        function animateRight(){
            leftPosition += 1;
            if (leftPosition<=300){
                    box.style.left = leftPosition+"px";
            } else {
                console.log("leftPosition = ",leftPosition);
                clearInterval(intervalRight);
                intervalLeft = setInterval(animateLeft, 20);
                }
        }

        function animateLeft(){
            if (leftPosition>=0){
                leftPosition -=1;
                box.style.left = leftPosition+"px";
            } else {
                console.log("leftPosition =", leftPosition);
                clearInterval(intervalLeft);
                setInterval(animateRight,20);
            }
        }

        intervalRight = setInterval(animateRight,20);   
    }



    window.onload = function(){
        preparePage();
    }
```

Comment: [Here's the complete code](http://pastebin.com/e9keWpEV). At first it starts to move quicker when it goes left, then it jumps from one side to the other and much further than intended 300 px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put the handle for the interval moving right into the variable. When you start moving left the second time, it won't stop the current inteval going right, it will try to stop the first interval again.

Change this:

```
setInterval(animateRight,20);
```

into:

```
intervalRight = setInterval(animateRight,20);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly now, but I admit I still don't understand why it was acting that way... It was moving faster and faster to the left with every cycle and and eventually started to jump from on end of the window to the other and causing my browser to crash.

Comment: Each time the box started to move left you tried to stop an interval that didn't exist any more, and started another interval. Now you have several intervals fighting about where the box should go, and starting more intervals all the time, until it overloads the browser.

Comment: Thanks again, I think I understand it now. I also found out that if I place leftPosition +=1; in the if statement it works fine even without setting the handle, although there're many running timers in the background (which suprisingly has no such an effect on browser performance as it had before). I might not have found out about the missing handle problem at all if I put the iteration in the if statement in the first place...

Comment: Moving `leftPosition += 1;` will just make the intervals fight less and start new intervals at a slower rate, but the browser will still crash eventually.